# sending php session variables to flash

Tags: php, flash, session

i am currently working on highscore system with php,mysql and flash. everything is done except a few things. i am struck at sending registered users and and guest users to the flash file. since 2 days im working but no luck. actually what my problem is in my highscore system i have provided the score submission to both registered as well as to guest user. if guest registered user submits the score then with the registered username the score should be submitted. whereas if guest submits the score the guest name appears whatever the guest types. i have tried with sessions but im new to this session programming. can anyone provide a small kind of example. please see my code....

```
$game_name = $_POST['game_name'];
$_SESSION['gamename'] = $game_name;

if($_POST['game_submit_btn']==1){
      //query here to add
      if($_SESSION['loggedinuserid']!=''){
        $_SESSION['hs_username']=$_SESSION['loggedinuser'];
        $_SESSION['hs_uid']=$_SESSION['loggedinuserid'];
      }elseif(strlen($_SESSION['hs_username'])<2){
        //$_SESSION['hs_user_name']='guest'.rand(0,999);
        $_SESSION['hs_username'] = 'Guest User';
        $_SESSION['hs_uid']=0;
      }
  }
```

And also one more thing is after submission of highscore i have bookmarked the site and again i revisited the site but the highscore values are not diaplaying..why it s happening....please reply me soon....awaiting for response....

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tutorial on how you can use the Zend Framework to communicate between Flash & PHP, this only addresses the last part of your question.
http://gotoandlearn.com/play.php?id=90

You said you bookmarked the site but your site would have to first make a PHP call to retrieve the score values stored in mysql in order to display them. Values could be "cached" in a SharedObject but, just like a cookie, this would only work with the browser that was used in the first place.

Check the docs for the SharedObject:
http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/

Now the rest of your question, is more of a PHP question, so I leave this to more specialized people here, although , were you to decide to use Zend Amf ,the Zend Framework has some great tools for authentication & access control...

Edit:
The point wasn't if you were using a framework or not , rather if you should use one.

I had a look at the site you mention in your comment... I was under the impression that you wanted to display the results in Flash, if not a simple MySQL query should do the trick... if you do , you can use Zend Amf or any other method you prefer to send the MySQL data to Flash.

Comment: hi patricks,
but here im not using any framework..and have a look at this site for reference http://www.gamesheep.com/highscores.php?id=the-champions-3d-game i have book marked this site and im revisiting the site again and again..